# Extract PathParam From The URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I want to extract pathparam from url; This is my url below

> [www.url.com/api/customer/897979/agent/6758/platform/win](http://www.url.com/api/customer/897979/agent/6758/platform/win)

Here  cutomer_id=897979 and agent_id=agent and platform_id=win

My Class extends AbstractFactoryFilter

```
 @Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {

        return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {

        }));
    };
}
```

I tried using the below,But it return null

```
    RequestPath path = exchange.getRequest().getPath();
```

I also tried something like this

```
 private HashMap<String, String> getPathParameters(String uri, String strUrlTemplate) {

    UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate(strUrlTemplate);
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    Boolean value = template.match(uri, parameters);
    return new HashMap<>(parameters);

}
```

UPDATE :

I want to extract cutomer_id=897979 and agent_id=agent and platform_id=win

from the below url

[www.url.com/api/customer/897979/agent/6758/platform/win](http://www.url.com/api/customer/897979/agent/6758/platform/win)

I am using AbstractFragemtFilter

```
public class FragmentFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Please clear the details

Comment: @AnishB.I have updated the question,please let me know what part is not clear

Comment: Are you using webflux ?

Comment: I am using AbstractFactoryFilter, public class ABC extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory